# Native DLL Not found

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a program that uses Tesseract to extract text from images. I made a Native C++ DLL that is used in C# via P/Invoke. My C# application is a console x64 based and the DLL is also 64 bit.

After deploying to a Windows Server I receive an error that suggets the DLL (one I've made) does not exists. The error message is below.

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'TesseractX64.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) at Utilities.Finance.PDFParser.PDF.OCRObject.GetUTF8Text(String path, String lang, String imgPath)

I know for sure that the DLL exists in that path. The TesseractX64.DLL is placed in the same folder as the C# application so it should work without any issues.

Here is my code:

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
[DllImport(@"TesseractX64.dll", EntryPoint = "GetUTF8Text", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr GetUTF8Text(string path, string lang, string imgPath);
```

What I have tried so far:

1. Set the DLLImport path to a relative path for example C:\DLL\Tesseract.DLL. Still same issue.
2. Installed Visual C++ 2005 - 2012 both x86 and x64. Still same issue.

It works perfectly fine on my Windows 7 x64 computer that I used to develop the program.

Comment: check if your based directory is the same where you start you application.

Comment: The message says `unable to load`. It doesn't necessarily mean that the .dll does not exist, but possibly that it can't be loaded because it depends itself on other .dll's that could not be found.

Comment: @dxiv: Thanks for pointing that out. I will have a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either:

1. The DLL cannot be found, or
2. One of the DLL's dependencies cannot be found.

Place the DLL in the same directory as the executable to ensure that it can be found.

Make sure that all the DLL's dependencies are met on each machine that needs to run your software. That will involve first working out what those dependencies are. The documentation for the DLL should tell you that information. Typically this means installing the MSVC runtime against which the DLL was linked.

You aren't allowed to redistribute the debug runtime. You'll want to make a release build of the native DLL even if the .NET code is in debug mode.

Comment: See also: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx)

Comment: [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is a nice utility to recursively find all the dependencies and which ones fail to load.

Comment: @David  I have copied all the required DLL files and there is no other DLL is required. the DLL is in the same directory as the executeable.

Comment: Well, the system disagrees with you. That the system threw `System.DllNotFoundException` tells you that it believes that other DLLs are required.

Comment: I've tried Dependency walker and I could see it uses MSVCP120D.DLL which is Visual c++ 2013 redist. package. I compiled it in VS 2013 so I have now installed it and restarted the server. I will get back to you guys in a minute.

Comment: That's the debug runtime. You aren't allowed to redistribute the debug runtime. You'll want to make a release build of the DLL.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What do you mean I am not allowed to? I downloaded the package from microsoft website... Do you think making a release version of DLL could fix the problem?

Comment: No. You downloaded the redistributable package from MS. That does not contain the debug runtime. You need to make a release build of the DLL, and install the appropriate redistributable for whichever version of the runtime you are linking against.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thank you!!!! I copied the MSVCR120D.DLL from my Dev machine to my server just to test it and it works! So will now make a release build of the DLL version and deploy. Thank you very very very much. Please make an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Er, I already answered. I'm not going to add the specific details that came out of the comments to my answer, because I answered the question that was asked. The detail in the comments were clarifications, but the points in my answer are accurate and I see no reason why you cannot accept it as it stands.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Forgot that the answer was from you. Only thought the comment. Thanks.

Comment: OK, thanks. For future reference though, even if it had been that way, it would not have been right to produce an answer based on the details to the comments here.  Answers should speak to the question.